# How to get a variable from front to a service worker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, web-push

#### Some context

I've created a service worker to send notifications to registered users.

It works well until I tried to implement a sort of id to each people who register to a service worker (to send notification).

*I do that because I have to delete old registration from my database, so I took the choice to let each users three registration (one for mobile device and two others for different navigator on computer) and if there is more, I want to remove from the database the older.*

#### Tools

I'm using nodejs, express and mySql for the database.

#### The issue

When I launch a subscription I got this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

I saw in an other post that it's because they try to JSON.parse what's already an object.

But in my case, I can't find where I parse, see the part which are concerned:

```
// service.js (service worker file)

// saveSubscription saves the subscription to the backend
const saveSubscription = async (subscription, usrCode) => { 
  const SERVER_URL = 'https://mywebsite:4000/save-subscription' 
  subscription = JSON.stringify(subscription);
  console.log(subscription); // I got here what I expect
  console.log(usrCode); // <-------------------------------- HERE I GOT UNDEFIND
  const response = await fetch(SERVER_URL, {
    method: 'post', 
    headers: { 
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json', 
    }, 
    body : {
      subscription: subscription,
      usrCode: usrCode
    }
  }) 
  return response
}
```

**But when I console.log(usrCode) in my inspector, I got the good value.**

**So how should I do to get the value in service.js**

Maybe the problem is from:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

At the beginning I thought that the issue is from the back (because I'm not really good with async function).

And here is the back, If maybe I got something wrong.

```
// index.js (backend)

// Insert into database
const saveToDatabase = async (subscription, usrCode) => {
  // make to connection to the database.
  pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    if (err) throw err; // not connected!
    console.log(usrCode);
    console.log(subscription);
    connection.query(`INSERT INTO webpushsub (webpushsub_info, webpushsub_code) VALUES ('${subscription}', '${usrCode}')`, function (err, result, fields) {
      // if any error while executing above query, throw error
      if (err) throw err;
      // if there is no error, you have the result
      console.log(result);
      connection.release();
    });
  });
}
// The new /save-subscription endpoint
app.post('/save-subscription', async (req, res) => {
  const usrCode = req.body.usrCode; // <------------------ I'm not sure about this part
  const subscription = req.body.subscription
  await saveToDatabase(JSON.stringify(subscription, usrCode)) //Method to save the subscription to Database
  res.json({ message: 'success' })
})
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify(subscription, usrCode)` makes no sense. The second parameter is the replacer function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: Where are you calling `saveSubscription`? If usrCode is undefined there it’s because the caller isn’t providing it.

Comment: The problem is with how you are calling saveSubscription. Since you do not show that, it is impossible to help.

Comment: @epascarello you are totally right, it's a mistake, I should do that `await saveToDatabase(JSON.stringify(subscription), usrCode)`.

Answer (score 0):

By searching on google, I've found [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B3oChLzQz5Q). So the reason why usrCode is undefined is because the service worker doesn't have access to a data stored in front.
First you have to pass it in the URL as following:

```
// swinstaller.js (front)

// SERVICE WORKER INITIALIZATION
const registerServiceWorker = async (usrCode) => {
  const swRegistration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('service.js?config=' + usrCode); //notice the file name
  return swRegistration;
}
```

And then get it in the service worker:

```
// service.js (service worker file)

// get the usrCode
const usrCode = new URL(location).searchParams.get('config');
```